# Asus Taichi21 Windows 8 Backlit Keyboard Not working

Tags: windows-8, asus-laptop

I bought an [Asus Taichi21](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/) notebook PC, did a factory reset and updated a few drivers. I notice the backlit keys are not lighting up before and after I updated drivers.

Buttons:
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> - Light goes down
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> - Light goes up

I'm currently using ATK Package v30

How do I get the backlit keys to light up?

Comment: The [manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/TAICHI21/E7553_Emanual_TAICHI21.pdf?_ga=1.33279868.350027036.1433076278) says those keys only work on selected models - what is the exact full model number?

Comment: RedGrittyBrick, thanks for reply it seems to be a hardware issue not a driver issue

Answer (score 0):

Just download & install the ATKPackage from the ASUS driver page. It worked for my Win 8.1 and Win 10 installations!